# SquareSpace Customer CSS Title Hover on Images

Tags: css, squarespace

I am using SquareSpace, and I am trying to add custom CSS to 3 images on my cover page. Currently on hover the images change opacity, and then a blue block appears with the title of the image. I am trying to make the blue block larger, but also make sure the block is trim to the actual image. As you can see in the following image, there is a little overhang:

[image: Overhang]

Any help would be appreciated!

```
.sqs-gallery-block-grid .slide .margin-wrapper .image-slide-title {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #1E75BB;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}

.sqs-gallery-block-grid .slide .margin-wrapper:hover .image-slide-title {
  display: block;
  opacity: 50;
  background-color: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.sqs-gallery-block-grid .slide .margin-wrapper .image-slide-title {
  font-family: adelle-sans;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.sqs-gallery-block-grid .slide .margin-wrapper:hover .image-slide-title {
  font-family: adelle-sans;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 75px) {
  .sqs-gallery-block-grid .slide .margin-wrapper .image-slide-title {
    opacity: 50;
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that your image has a problem, can you fix it so we can help you?

Comment: What you're looking to target is `.sqs-gallery-block-grid .sqs-gallery-design-grid-slide .margin-wrapper`. From there you can style it however you want :)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is each image has different dimensions and share a common class (`div.image-slide-title`).

There are 2 ways I could think of, either photoshop all images to equal dimensions (say `248px` wide as the last one) and impact `div.image-slide-title` with the same as above, only this time `248px` width should work for all of them.

[image]

**Or**, isolate each image with a new class/id (*example*: `div.image-slide-title-1`, `div.image-slide-title-2` & `div.image-slide-title-3`) and give it the following in addition to the proper width:

- `margin: 0 auto;` to center.
- Give the image's `width` to the blue block (*example*: last one should be `width: 248px;`)

Comment: Fantastic that worked....I went with option 1! I appreciate the in-depth explanation, it was super helpful.

Comment: Sophie glad it worked, please consider marking the answer correct if it helped you, thank you. Regards.